# Redirect por código a nuevo URL

Tags: reactjs, url, redirección

Necesito que según una condición me cargue una nueva URL y borre de la pila la URL en la que se está.

Por ejemplo:

```
const [home, setHome]=useState(false)

if(home){
    return(<Redirect push={true} to="/home/" />);
}
if (ingresar){
   setHome(true)
  }
```

El problema que presento es que cuando se cumple que home es igual a true, la URL cambia pero la página queda en blanco y solo se carga si se hace actualizar en el navegar. ¿Por qué? ¿Cómo es posible solucionarlo? que cuando se cumple que home=true se cargue completamente la URL home.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: De dónde viene la variable `ingresar`, ¿Es una `prop` del componente? Saludos

Comment: Hola. Si es un hook del componente.

Comment: No veo ningún problema, si pudieras compartir el código de `ingresar`, es decir su hook y dónde lo cambias.